# How to split result in tow cells

Tags: google-sheets

using google sheets I have the following formulae :

`=CONCAT( SUMIFS($H$3:$H$39,$C$3:$C$39,C3,$E$3:$E$39,"SELL"),C3)`

Now I want to improve this formulae, instead of concatenating the the same cell, I would like the value of the first part SUMIFS and the value of C3 to be placed
in two contingents cells.

Comment: Don't use `CONCAT()` function. Put `Sumifs` to a cell and `=C3` to another cell. You can also use `SPLIT()` function.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
={SUMIFS($H$3:$H$39, $C$3:$C$39, C3, $E$3:$E$39, "SELL"), C3}
```

Comment: This looks very similar to what OP has tried, could you point out for my novice eyes what makes this solution work?

Comment: @C.Peck OP successfully used `CONCAT(SUMIF(), C3)` which outputs the result into one single cell. now OP wants to split this result into two contingents cells with single formula - hence the proposed answer/solution